# how to rename the old files or backup them into a folder when there are file names collision?

Tags: backup, rename

As you know, the default windows copy handler renames the new files if you choose "keeps both files" . What program can i use to rename the old files instead? or better, put all the old files into a backup folder at the same location, each with its own path structure?

Comment: Use Total Commander. It has these options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync --backup` would do what you want. You can specify a suffix for old files using `--suffix`, or move old files to a different folder using `--backup-dir`.

Comment: Thank you so much. its exact what i've been googling for so long

Answer (score 2):

This script puts all duplicate files from `%DestinationFolder%`, into a backup  directory called `$Backup_%date%_%time%` at the root of `%DestinationFolder%`, prefixed by `%prefix%` variable, which is `$Backup_` by default. You can customize this value.

```
@echo off
set Folder=
set DestinationFolder=
set prefix=$Backup_
set suffix=%date%_%time%
set suffix=%suffix:/=-%
set suffix=%suffix::=-%
cd /d "%Folder%"
for /R %%a in (.) do (
    set PTH=%%a
    call :DUP
)
xcopy /herkvy "%Folder%" "%DestinationFolder%" 1>nul 2>&1
goto :eof

:DUP
set PTH=%PTH:\.=%
call set PTH=%%PTH:%Folder%=%%
type nul>"%tmp%\FileList"
for /f "tokens=4,* delims= " %%b in ('dir /a "%Folder%%PTH%" ^| find "/" ^| find /i /v "<DIR>"') do (
    echo %%c>>"%tmp%\FileList"
)
for /f "tokens=4,* delims= " %%d in ('dir /a "%DestinationFolder%%PTH%" ^| find "/" ^| find /i /v "<DIR>"') do (
    find /i "%%e" "%tmp%\FileList" 1>nul 2>&1 && (
         if not exist "%DestinationFolder%\%prefix%%suffix%%PTH%" md "%DestinationFolder%\%prefix%%suffix%%PTH%"
         move "%DestinationFolder%%PTH%\%%e" "%DestinationFolder%\%prefix%%suffix%%PTH%\%%e" 1>nul 2>&1
    )
)
exit /b
```

*Note: Please set `Folder` to the path of folder you want to backup, and `DestinationFolder` to the path of destination (Backup) folder **Without Baclslash At The End!** Example:*

***Correct:***

```
set Folder=C:\project\files
set DestinationFolder=D:\Data\backup
```

***Wrong:***

```
set Folder=C:\project\files\
set DestinationFolder=D:\Data\backup\
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. i found a neat GUI utility for rsync, called Grsync, in other answer while waiting. that should serve my need for now. i'll save this for multiple backups situation. Although this seems to run some problems:
1. sub directories in the backup folder is turned in to an inaccessible file with no extension. i can only see files from the root
2.each sub directory has their own backup folder. is there any way to gather them all into a backup folder at the root ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It used to try to copy folder names as files, that's why you got files without extensions. I fixed it now. Please forgive me if I'm not a batch geek, I did my best but it's not so speedy. If you want to customize Backup folder name or anything, just leave me a comment.

Comment: Oh no, dont be sorry lol. Im not your boss. Im glad that strangers on the net are bothered to help.   i just tried the new batch. it doesnt seem to backup anything now, just overwrites the old files and creates an empty backup folder. can you look into that ? also, is there a way to keep the path structure of each file in the backup folder ? i dont want to manually find their places when doing restore tasks. Grsync can already do this for me but i dont know how to make it name the backup folder with date+time suffix yet

Comment: I'm not sorry because you're my boss, because it wasn't well tested. If it created an empty backup folder, that's because it only backs up files, that are going to overwrite! Do you want to put all files present before sync, into backup folder? Yes, it's possible to keep folder structure, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Updated, now it moves all the files, regardless of duplication into backup folder (as requested). Now it's pretty damn fast. Good Luck!

Comment: i just want to backup the old duplications. other files and folder should remain untouched

Comment: Updated once again. If it still doesn't work, there's a problem with your command line interpreter, or I'm totally insane! I hope it's not the latter :)

Comment: seems like i gotta bother you again. it doesn't back up any files, only folders now, the old files are overwritten. i've tested it on 3 different computers

Comment: I have no idea! Except the first one which created files without extension, all other versions I've sent you works. I can even upload a video of it working! What do you set for `Folder` and `DestinationFolder`?

Comment: Just D:\old and D:\new.i set them up like this

D:\old
D:\old\test1.txt.
D:\old\do not move.txt
D:\old\test2 
D:\old\\test2\test2.txt 

D:\new\test1.txt. 
D:\new\test2
D:\new\test2\test2.txt.  

i want the test files in "old" to be put in backup folder with their respective folder structure before writing new files. the "do not move" should stay untouched. sorry i dont know how to break lines. i'm new to this place

Comment: No, problem. I'm new here too. If I got it right, `D:\old` is your `DestinationFolder` and `D:\new` is your `Folder`. I created exact same folder structure (even under D:\) and ran the script. `Do not move.txt` remains untoched, `test1.txt` and `test2.txt` are replaced, and old versions are moved with accordance to this structure:  `D:\old\$Backup_%date%_%time%\test1.txt` and `D:\old\$Backup_%date%_%time%\test2\test2.txt`. What I suspect, is you put a space at the end of path like `"D:\old "` or `"D:\new "`.

Comment: i just tested it on a freshly installed windows and it works fine. something is wrong with my system. thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Glad it helped! I saw systems experiencing problems with command line interpreter, giving errors where other systems work fine. Good Luck!